# Subtle Carefulness in use of AM-GM inequality

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, maxima-minima, trigonometric-series, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The question :-

[image: Q1]

The solution given in textbook :-

[image: Their answer]

My answer :-

[image: Ans 2]

I am not able to identify which is right. I thought mine may be wrong due to squaring or reciprocal taking but I don't think it is causing any defect as all the terms are positive.

I have been really confused for 2 days. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Source** :- JEE Advance 2001

***Edit*** :- Thank god! I now know where my solution is wrong.. it was very interesting!! But **please help in finding minima of expression whose maximum we found** .

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to comment since I don't have enough reputation, so I am adding the answer here.
Note how the minimum value of the angles can be 0 degrees and maximum can be 90 degrees, hence the minima of this function will be 0.

Comment: When all will be 0, the product of cots of all angles will not be equal to 1